# How to write my_strchr() in C

Tags: c, function

Right now I hope to write my own `my_strchr()` in the C language.

I checked that the answer should be like this:

```
char *my_strchr(const char *src1, int c) {
    
    while (*src1 != '\0') { //when the string goes to the last, jump out 
        if (c == *src1) {
            return src1; 
        }
        src1++;
    }
    return NULL;     
}
```

I'm quite confused by:

1. why we use `*src1`  in the `while` loop condition `(*src1 != '\0')`, is `*src1` a pointer to the `const char*`? Can we just use `src1` instead?
2. When we return value and `src1++`, we do not have that `*src1`, why?
3. For this function, it in fact prints the whole string after the required characters, but why is that? Why does it not print only the character that we need to find?

Comment: 1. `*src1` is checking the char content. `src` would just check the pointer. The content needs to be checked because it is look for the end of the string which is marked by a `\0` NUL char. 2. `src1++` is moving to the next character in the string. 3. The function does not print anything.

Comment: You should handle the case where `c` is `'\0'`; it needs to return a pointer to the trailing nul if you want to replicate the standard behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `src1` is the *pointer* to the character, but we need the *character* itself. It's the same reason as in point 2, but the other way round.
2. If you write `return *src1;` you simply return the *character* you've found, that's always `c`, so your function would be pointless. You want to return the *pointer* to that char.
3. Because that's what the function is supposed to do. It returns the *pointer* to the first character `c` found. So printing the string pointed by that pointer prints the rest of the string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think I get confused by the two purpose of *(asterik). it cannot only declarew a new pointer, but also deference the pointer.

Comment: @floatingstarlight: exactly! the `*` in `char *src1;` and the one in `c = *str1;` have a very different meaning. And `*` has yet another meaning in `c = a * b;`

Answer (score 1):

It's important here to remember that in C a string is a series of characters that ends with a null (`'\0'`) character. We reference the string in our code using a character pointer that points to the beginning of the string. When we pass a string as a parameter to a function what we're really getting is a pointer to the first character in the string.

Because of this fact, we can use pointer math to increment through a string. The pattern:

```
while (*src1 != '\0') {
    //do stuff
    src1++;
}
```

is a very common idiom in C. We might phrase it in English as:
While the value of the character in the string we are looking at (dereference `src1` with the `*` operator) is not (inequality operator `!=`) the end of string indicator (null byte, `0` or `'\0'`), do some stuff, then move the pointer to point to the next character in the string (increment operator `++`).

We often use the same kind of code structure to process other arrays or linked lists of things, comparing pointers to the `NULL` pointer.

To question #2, we're returning the value of the pointer from this function `src1` and not the value of what it points to `*scr1` because the question that this function should answer is "Where is the first instance of character `c` in the string that starts at the location pointed to by `src1`.

Question #3 implies that the code that calls this function is printing a string that starts from the pointer returned from this function. My guess is that the code looks something like this:

```
printf("%s", my_strchr(string, 'a'));
```

`printf()` and friends will print from the location provided in the argument list that matches up with the `%s` format specifier and then keep printing until it gets to the end of string character (`'\0'`, the null terminator).

Comment: The null byte or null character is spelled in lower case, `NULL` is a macro for a null pointer constant.

Comment: You're correct. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

In C, a string is basically an array of char, an array is a pointer pointing to the first element in the array, and a pointer is the memory address of the value. Therefore:

1. You can use `*src1` to get the value that it is pointing to.
2. `src1++` means to +1 on the address, so you are basically moving where the pointer is pointing at.
3. Since you are returning a pointer, it is essentially equal to a string (char array).

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! I get it

Comment: *an array is a pointer pointing to the first element in the array* not true! An array is **not** a pointer. Arrays implicitly convert to a pointer to their first element when used in most expression contexts, such as when passed to a function. Furthermore a pointer is not the memory address of the value, its value is a memory address.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to *Jabberwocky*'s answer, please note that the code in the question has 2 bugs:

- `c` must be converted to `char` for the comparison with `*src1`: `strchr("ABC", 'A' + 256)` returns a pointer to the string literal unless `char` has more than 8 bits.
- Furthermore, if `c` converted to a `char` has the value `0`, a pointer to the null terminator should be returned, not `NULL` as in the posted code.

Here is a modified version:

```
char *my_strchr(const char *s, int c) {
    for (;;) {
        if ((char)c == *s) {
            return src1; 
        }
        if (*s++ == '\0') {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the notification!
1.  For the first bug, which makes me a little bit confused, I assume that  c will convert the int c to char c automatically? (I run my code on terminal, and it seems works).

Comment: @floatingstarlight: `c` does not implicitly convert to `char`, merely the opposite: in `c == *str1` the conversion is called integer promotion if type `char` is smaller than `int`, `*str1` is promoted to an `int` and the comparison is performed on the `int` values.  For example the original version of `my_strchr("\xFF", 0xFF)` would return `NULL` if the type `char` is signed because the fist `char` in the string has a value of `-1` which is different from `0xFF`.  Casting `c` as `(char)` solves the issue because `(char)0xFF == -1`.